# Bluetooth: Send ACL command

Tags: android, bluetooth, protocols

I would like to connect to my headset and send it an `ACL` command to make it ring.

However, so far I only found a method to connect via `RFCOMM` to a Bluetooth Device. Is that the only way or is it possible to send an ACL command as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are confused about the protocols.  [ACL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L2CAP#Asynchronous_connection-oriented_.5BLogical_Transport.5D_.28ACL.29) is a low-level transport protocol used by BT devices to send data.  It has nothing to do with application specific meanings of the data.  Above ACL links is a protocol called L2CAP, which is still essentially a data pipe.  Above L2CAP you get into application specific protocols like RFCOMM.  Rather than RFCOMM, Headset Profile (HSP) is used to do things like ringing a phone.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_profile#Headset_Profile_.28HSP.29

Comment: Thanks for explaing that =) I guess accessing the HSP is not possible?